# How do I turn off the colors in Laravel's PHPUnit task?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, ansi-colors

I'm testing under Windows and the command prompt doesn't do so well with the ANSI color codes that appear by default.  How can I turn off the color display when I'm using Laravel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The file **\laravel\cli\tasks\test\stub.xml** is used to generate the PhpUnit configuration file for tests.  (A new configuration file is generated and deleted every time you run an artisan test task.)  To turn off colors, change the first line of stub.xml from `<phpunit colors="true"` to `<phpunit colors="false"` (for Laravel 3)

**Update:** For Laravel 4, the file is `phpunit.xml` and is found in the root folder. The change is still to set `colors="false"`.

Comment: You saved me from so much twitching. I am eternally grateful.

Comment: Laravel on Stackexchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel?referrer=VUgOWgZpXyO753uZWv1VMg2

Comment: This is also helpful for running tests inside PHPStorm. With `colors="true"`, the IDE gets some sort of *ugly* color codes.

Answer (score 3):

You can add colors in windows command prompt.Its great for spotting errors and success. I followed this http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows/